# Error in Angular core for a property not exists

Tags: angular, typescript

```
Property 'ɵunwrapWritableSignal' does not exist on type 'typeof import("c:/Users/akshitha.jain/source/repos/AngularVersion/japaniop_SPA_AIR4227/node_modules/@angular/core/index")'.ngtsc(2339)
request.component.ts(19, 34): Error occurs in the template of component RequestComponent.
```

So I am getting this error on below html code in `[(ngModel)]="this.requestEditInfo.tsDetail"`
Please help.

```html
<div>
<kendo-textarea resizable="none" class="form_style1"n[(ngModel)]="this.requestEditInfo.tsDetail"></kendo-textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: You haven't really given enough code to be able to diagnose your issue, but I do see a letter `n` added right before your `n[(ngModel)]` which might be an issue

Comment: How does `requestEditInfo` get loaded in your component? It seems likely it is undefined.

Comment: sorry n was added by mistake while posting question @ChrisBarr

Comment: no , requestEditInfo has been defined in my code. @AdamExchange

Comment: try removing "this" as it would be ambiguous in the template context, just bind to "requestEditInfo.tsDetail" (assuming "requestEditInfo" is a public field on your component class, and it is an object with "tsDetail" property)

Answer (score 0):

This problem is due to the recent version changes of [Angular language service](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Angular.ng-template) from Visual studio code extension.
Downgrading the version to [17.2.1](https://github.com/angular/vscode-ng-language-service/issues/2001) fixes the issue.

Comment: Hi, My angular version is 17.1.2

Comment: Are you using this visual studio code extension [Angular language service](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Angular.ng-template) ? If so, could you check the version of this extension ?